# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

Вывожу через echo следующее:

```
echo "<a id="example2" href=".$arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC']." width=".$arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['WIDTH']." height=".$arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['HEIGHT']."><img src=".$arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC']." width=200 border=0 alt=".$arElement['NAME']." title=".$arElement['NAME']." /></a>";
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где с синтаксисом накололся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте экранировать кавычки атрибута id.

```
echo "<a id=\"\"></a>";
```

Comment: Да, спасибо. Уже нашел. Поставил слеши в атрибуте id.

Answer (score 0):

Да вы посмотрите хотя бы на подсветку кода и сразу же увидите что у вас example2 распознаётся как T_STRING. Кавычки то закрываются после id=.